# How to correctly scale an iframe inside a grid?

Tags: html, css, reactjs, iframe, tailwind-css

**Project**

- **Tailwind**
- **React**

  When unscaling an iframe it messes with the iframe position inside the grid.

  **Expected**: After unscaling the iframe it should keep the same position but with reduced size.

  **Behavior**: After unscaling the iframe it is messing with the position of the iframe.

  **Father component**

```
const ContainersView = () => {
  
  return <div className="grid 
            h-[100vh]
            absolute
            !ml-[100px]
            w-[85vw]
            
            xlg:grid-cols-3 xlg:left-[140px]
            lg:left-[150px] lg:grid-cols-2 lg:ml-12 lg:gap-y-24

            grid-rows-2

            mt-4
            mb-4      
            ">
    <DockerIframe />
  </div>
}
```

**Child component**

```
const DockerIframe = () => {

  return (
    <div className=''>
      <button className='bg-cyan-800 text-white z-50'>mouse and keyboard</button>
      <iframe


        allowFullScreen={true}
        src={`http://url:8080/`}
        className={`

        transform
        xlg:scale-[0.4]
        lg:scale-[0.5]

        h-[800px] w-[1038px] 
        `}
      />
    </div>
  )
}
```

[image: Comparison with unscale and scale, and also the expected result.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this problem by adjusting the position of iframe by adding some hardcoded values on DockerIframe component.

Would be still nice to see a clever aproach on this. But for now this works.

```
    relative

    lg:scale-[0.45]
    lg:-top-[220px]
    lg:-left-[287px]
    
    xlg:scale-[0.4]
    xlg:-top-[240px]
    xlg:-left-[312px]
```